# How do i process data from multiple JSON files in Tableau to create a dashboard?

Tags: json, mobile, tableau-api, analytics

I have multiple JSON files containing data for mobile analytics. Each JSON file contains an array of multiple objects with different event types. Each event type would have a different set of fields (some key value pairs overlap though). How do i process the JSON files in Tableau to create my dashboard?

For example, I have to check which JSON object corresponds to this particular event of user 1 sending a message and calculate how long it takes for the message to be sent by referring to the event when the message is received by the other party.

Answer (score 0):

Try a wildcard union for the files(you can select the schema levels) and create an extract and then use this extract to build the dashboard.

Comment: Does this require Tableau Prep? Or is desktop sufficient? Thanks!

Comment: Desktop would do.